# Problems installing Empathy

Tags: installation, empathy

I'm trying to install empathy.

Current version has to be installed from source, but needs a list of things that have to be installed one by one.
Previous version is in repository, but blinks (opens, then right after that, closes).
Previous version of the previous version:

- rpm -ivh rpmfilename gives me failed dependencies.
- `apt-cache search -showpkg empathy` shows general empathy information and a telepathy too, but not the rpm file name
- taking the rpm file name from a Google search result, `apt-get install package=empathy-2.30.1-2pclos2010` says package package (twice, really) not found
- installing apturl, clicking the rpm file link, opening it with apturl, installation gui starts, but fails
- opening the rpm file with Synaptic doesn't work
- opening the rpm file with /usr/bin/apt-get doesn't work

What now?

Comment: I'm confused. Are you trying to install an RPM, or a DEB?  Or via source? If your trying to install from source, you can use Checkinstall (http://www.asic-linux.com.mx/~izto/checkinstall/) to make an RPM or DEB file to install, so you can easily share or update

Comment: rpm, pclinuxos uses synaptic, but rpm with synaptic

Answer (score 1):

You will want to do:

```
apt-get install empathy
```

The reason it wasn't working with

```
apt-get install package=empathy-2.30.1-2pclos2010
```

And saying `package` twice was because it thought you were looking for a package named `package`. So it was telling you: We couldn't find the package called `package`.

Comment: apt-get install empathy will install the repository's current, the one that blinks, which is one version before the real current, which must be installed from source

Comment: That's probably because the one from source is the unstable version, and hasn't been put into the package repositories yet. So you'll either have to wait for it to show up in the repos, or try to install from source.

Comment: if I install a older version it may work, because it works in other people's computers

Comment: If you want to install an older version, do `apt-get install empathy=VERSION` and replace `VERSION` with the version of empathy you want to install.

Comment: Mr. Man, we're almost done. I have an empathy rpm file, I think I have to apt-cache add it, then apt-get install it. Can I apt-cache add empatest.rpm, then apt-get install empatest? I'm going to break my computer...

Comment: I don't have much experience with `rpm` but I think that you could just do the command `rpm empatest.rpm` to install it.

Comment: I had tried rpm -ivh packagefile and it didn't work. See why people call it dependency hell? lol! :-)

Comment: I'm going to update the question with the rpm command.

Answer (score 0):

apt-get install  is the way to use apt-get.  Your output (package package not found) suggests it is searching for a package by the name of package.

Comment: apt-get install empathy-2.30.1-2pclos2010 says package not found too

Comment: The name of the package is "empathy", not "empathy-2.30.1-2pclos2010".